# Made a local copy of live-site: all paths generate error 404

Tags: installation

Drupal version: 6

I've made a local copy of a site that is live, has loads of content and is configured to run in the Kurdish language.

Steps I did to accomplish this:
- Made a tarball of the Drupal installation and extracted it on my localhost
- Dumped the live-database and imported it locally
- Modified settings.php to reflect local database settings

When browsing to the local installation, the front-page seems to work fine (except for a few pictures not showing up, as well as the facebook like box generating a 404 error). Except: when clicking on any url, of any node-type, a 404 error is generated.

I tried to fix it with this proposed solution: http://www.paulmarc.org/learn/drupal/rebuilding-site-urls, but to no avail. It seems to me I have to rebuild the site, however: even invoking that path does not work and generates a 404 and is thus inaccessible.

Comment: nevermind the `as well as the facebook like box generating a 404 error` comment: I just realized that is because I have blocked facebook via my /etc/hosts file. Nevermind; the general problem still stands

Comment: this should work without 'rebuilding urls', unless there is something working against you. Few questions -  do you have clean urls enabled on your local environment? Are you using any kind of secure pages module or other redirection module from your database? Has the .htaccess file in your installation been modified in any way from the core version?

Comment: @schnippy, mod rewrite/clean urls are enabled, no secure pages/redirection module and the .htaccess has not been modified. Everything is a 1 on 1 copy of the live-instance.

Comment: have you tried fully flushing cache from the comand line (ex. drush cc all)?

Comment: @schnippy, tried that: same problem. I have reinstalled the local instance via git, resulting also in the same problem: 1) created git repo of my live-site 2) cloned that to a staging repo 3) cloned the staging repo to my localhost and 4) making sure .htaccess and settings.php reflect local settings. To no avail: 404's allover the place. Even a simple url as localhost/drupal/user gives a not found error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. It appeared that I installed the mod rewrite module, but didn't activate it in my default site profile (as per these instructions: http://www.seangw.com/wordpress/2012/01/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-in-apache2-ubuntu/). Did that and everything works fine now. Woops, feel kind of stupid now.